# Linq select into model and set properties

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

In .NET Core 2.X, I was able to use this code below:

```
var bookings = await db.Tasks
        .Where(c => c.ClientId == clientId && c.IsDeleted == false && c.Start > startOfThisMonth && c.End < endOfThisMonth)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Start)
        .Select(x => new SpecialTaskVm(new TaskViewModel(x, null))
        {
            client = x.Client,
            carer = x.Booking.SingleOrDefault(b => b.SlotNumber == 1).Carer,
            carer2 = x.Booking.SingleOrDefault(bk => bk.SlotNumber == 2).Carer
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```

However the same code in .net core 3.X results in this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: When called from 'VisitMemberInit', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitMemberInit' and change it to not visit children of this type.

I could really do with selecting in the way I do above as each model does some modification to some properties and each model is used elsewhere separately.

I am also trying to avoid a `foreach` as it seems that would be inefficient.

I have tried passing the properties I need to set, into the model and setting them in the model like that. Same error occurs.

```
//This action method will return data for current month.
var startOfThisMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
var endOfThisMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month, 1);

var bookings = await db.Tasks
        .Where(c => c.ClientId == clientId && c.IsDeleted == false && c.Start > startOfThisMonth && c.End < endOfThisMonth)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Start)
        .Select(x => new SpecialTaskVm(new TaskViewModel(x, null))
        {
            client = x.Client,
            carer = x.Booking.SingleOrDefault(b => b.SlotNumber == 1).Carer,
            carer2 = x.Booking.SingleOrDefault(bk => bk.SlotNumber == 2).Carer
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```

I expect for the list of tasks to be returned in the form of `List<SpecialTaskVm>` with `Client`, `Carer` and `Carer2` set.

Comment: It doesn't like the null in TaskViewModel(x, null).  How is TaskViewModel defined?  It looks like a bug in 2X was fixed in 3X.

Comment: Nope, sometimes I pass in a dictionary which changes how some of the properties. So when I pass in null in place of the dictionary, the model knows to set the properties slightly differently. I use this model a lot in .net core 3.0. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: It's a bit unusual to use a constructor *and* object initialisation syntax in the same code, to me that's already a code smell. If I were you, I would create an intermediate list that only gets values from the DB, then project that data into your `SpecialTaskVm` objects.

Comment: But does your constructors return a NULL?

Comment: @jdweng How could a constructor return a null? They return an instance or throw an exception.

Comment: @DavidG your suggestion sounds like a proper way to do it. Would you be able to briefly elaborate on how you would implement? I think I get what you're saying but just want to be sure.

Comment: That is what the error is stating.  I would like to see the constructor.

Comment: @jdweng No, the error isn't stating that at all, that error is coming from the Entity Framework internals as it tries to parse through the expression. Like I said before, it's simply not possible for a constructor to return null, and regardless, EF wouldn't be able to get into that code in the first place.

Comment: Event if an exception is occurring?

Comment: @jdweng When EF is playing around with expressions, it hasn't even begun to run SQL, let alone execute any `Select` projections.

Comment: @DavidG: Do not understand your response which has nothing to do with exceptions.  Why couldn't the exception occur while EF is playing around with the expression?

Comment: @jdweng OK, so EF pulls apart the expression to generate the required SQL, while it's doing that it doesn't *execute* the expression at all, it's just extracting the metadata. So it will not try to run the constructor for that object until much later in the process. Even if it did execute it and throw, we would almost certainly see that exception rather than the expression exception.

Comment: Looks like this is a reported bug and is being fixed https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18888

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unusual to use a constructor and object initialisation syntax in the same code, to me that's already a code smell.

If I were you, I would create an intermediate list that only gets values from the database, then project that data into your `SpecialTaskVm` objects. For example:

```
// First get the data from the database in a simple form we can parse through later
var bookingData = await db.Tasks
        .Where(c => c.ClientId == clientId && c.IsDeleted == false && c.Start > startOfThisMonth && c.End < endOfThisMonth)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Start)
        .Select(x => new // Use an anonymous type
        {
            Client = x.Client,
            Carer = x.Booking.SingleOrDefault(b => b.SlotNumber == 1).Carer,
            Carer2 = x.Booking.SingleOrDefault(bk => bk.SlotNumber == 2).Carer
        })
        .ToListAsync();

// Now we massage the data into a format we can use
var bookings = bookingData
        .Select(x => new SpecialTaskVm(new TaskViewModel(x, null))
        {
            client = x.Client,
            carer = x.Carer,
            carer2 = x.Carer2
        })
        .ToList();
```

Additionally, I would potentially recommend changing the `SpecialTaskVm` constructor (or add a new one) to include the new fields.

Comment: Very clever. Thanks.